# Linker input modifying for graphics projects of C++ (PPP)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I wanted to do the exercises of chapter 12 of Programming Principles and Practice using C++ book. But I had to modify the **linker input** to "*fltkd.lib;wsock32.lib;comctl32.lib;fltkjpegd.lib;fltkimagesd.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)*". Then it compiled. That is, for each project I have to modify the linker input.
Isn't there any way to don't modify the linker input in each project or somehow do it generally one time and don't need to do that for the rest of the projects?

PS: My compiler is Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it by [**setting the property sheets (`.vsprops`)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

> [...] You can use property sheets to create project configurations that can be applied to multiple projects since project settings that are defined in .vsprops files are inheritable, unlike project settings defined in Project Files (.vcproj files). Therefore, a project configuration defined in a .vcproj file can inherit project settings from one or more property sheets (.vsprops files). [...]

Under `Property Manager` View, you can setup the property that you want and it will generate a `.vsprops` file on your project folder. Then you can copy this `.props` file to other project and loading it will enable you to have the same property setting.

P.S. The property sheets (`.vsprops`) is also workable for setting other properties, including include directories, library directories etc.

You can check out [Sharing project properties in Visual C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319827/Sharing-project-properties-in-Visual-Cplusplus) for step-by-step examples.